# Are there any plugins for Craft 3?

Tags: plugin-development, plugins, craft3

Are there any Craft 3 plugins yet? They would be useful as examples for porting/writing other Craft 3 plugins.

Comment: You may want to consider switching the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:**

Since Craft 3 was officially released (4/4/18), all plugins can be found in the [Craft Plugin Store](https://plugins.craftcms.com/)!

---

**Original:**

Now that the [Craft 3 Beta](https://craftcms.com/3) is out and we’re done making breaking changes to plugin APIs, we’re keeping a master list of Craft 3-compatible plugins at **[github.com/craftcms/plugins](https://github.com/craftcms/plugins)**.

Answer (score 11):

Here are some.

- [Store Hours (P&T)](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/StoreHours/tree/craft3)
- [match input](https://github.com/marionnewlevant/craft-mn_matchinput/tree/craft3)
- [Mandrill (P&T)](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Mandrill)
- [Entry Count](https://github.com/putyourlightson/craft-entry-count/tree/craft3)
- [Minify](https://github.com/nystudio107/minify/tree/craft3) (9/17/2016)
- [MN Twig Perversion](https://github.com/marionnewlevant/craft-twig_perversion/tree/craft3) (9/19/2016)
- [Stamp](https://github.com/aelvan/Stamp-Craft/tree/craft3) (9/21/2016)
- [Inlin](https://github.com/aelvan/Inlin-Craft/tree/craft3) (9/21/2016)

Mention more in the comments, and I will add to this list.

Comment: Ported my two simplest plugins over: Stamp (https://github.com/aelvan/Stamp-Craft/tree/craft3) and Inlin (https://github.com/aelvan/Inlin-Craft/tree/craft3). :)